# Showing a marker on an embedded Open Street Map based on address data

Tags: javascript, geocoding, openstreetmap

At the moment I serve pages showing a google map with a marker using an address retrieved from my database. I currently use a fairly simple piece of javascript code to add that marker by geocoding. My js code is dynamically generated by php. All is static except the  "query" definition which gets initialized with the address search string.

I new to OSM and did some research to see if it can achieve this. At the moment I'm not sure it can. I found there are several js api's like OpenLayers which I'd need to use.

To sum it up :

**How to add and show a single marker to an OSM, where the location is based on an address instead of a latitude/longtitude pair?**

My current google based code is:

```js
<script>
var geocoder; var map; var marker;
var query = 'Deutschland, Berlin, Platz der Republik 1, 11011';

function initialize()
{        
var companyLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(51.964577109947506, 5.07568359375);      
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = { zoom: 11, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
codeAddress();
}

function codeAddress()
{
var address = query;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map, 
     position: results[0].geometry.location,
     title: "Bundestag",
     labelContent: "",
     labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
     labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
     labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
  });        
  } else {
    $('#map_canvas').html('<p style="margin: 15px">Address could not be found</p>');
  }
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Reverse geocoding requires a latitude/longitude pair instead of an address input. This is not what is needed, the question is specific about that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Not going to write the code for you, but that wiki page has detailed information on how to call the Nominatim geocoding service.

Comment: The detailed information you mention is in fact very minimal. It covers the plain xml messages. Not how to send them and not how to display the outcome. In fact the wiki doesn't explain any of the required javascript coding.

Comment: Nominatim seems the way to go. For using the JavaScript API the documentation at this site is much more useful than the wiki: [Nominatim on open.mapquestapi.com](http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v6.1.0/nominatim.html)

Comment: @Johan the examples show XML structures, however the very first part of the paramaters documentation describes how to select json. You'll get json instead of XML, with the same structure.

Comment: I recon that the doc contains this, sort of. However it is not a learning resource at all. I wouldn't recommend it to anyone in its current state. It's written like an rfc: scary, difficult and without real world examples. The url I posted is an actual guide through the most common use cases.

Comment: Please add the url to the answer for reference purposes